# some products are not billing and checking out

Tags: category-products

I am using magento 1.9.2.0. some of my store simple products from specific categories are not ordering, it got stuck on billing info. But when i tried to order a product from different categories it got successfully ordered.

also, when i add product from both categories it also get successful order.

please help me to solve this.

Comment: What is the product type you mentioned in the question? like simple, virtual

Comment: All the product are simple

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad to give a definite answer, but I can give some advice.

#### Testing (on a copy of the production system!)

1. Try to find out, what the products in these specific categories have in common.
2. Change those attributes on a product until you see a difference
3. If you suspect the category itself to be the problem, verify that by moving one product to a different category

#### Debugging

1. Inspect the requests during checkout in the browser network console. Are there error messages? A 503 error means there was a PHP error.
2. Check your webserver or PHP error logs.
3. Check `var/log/exception.log` in Magento (logging should be activated in the configuration (system > configuration > developer > debug)
4. Reproduce the error on a development system and use XDebug to go through the code step by step. The previous steps should give you enough information to find places in the code where to set breakpoints.